# how get the PATH of "Configuration File (php.ini)" from http?

Tags: php

using CLI:

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

return just my target: **path to Configuration File**

but how get the same from Apache? (http://)

[image]

the code

```
<?php
phpinfo(1);
```

return my target but this require filter output and use `preg_match('/PATERN/', $output, $string)...`

also the code

```
<?php
php_ini_loaded_file();
```

and

```
<?php
php_ini_scanned_files();
```

return **files.ini** loaded, but again: I need the value **Path** returned by

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

is possible from http?

(if instructions from line command is called **CLI**, what is the name for code from http??)

Comment: Is this not helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/where-can-i-find-php-ini

Comment: not is my target

Comment: Why do you need to expose server internals publically? What are you trying to _do_ that makes you think that's part of the solution to _that_ problem?

Comment: You could use shell_exec . Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17111106/3710053